# Homepage Content

Tags: magento2, product, home

I just installed magento 2, I added two products that do not appear here in the index. Do I need to do any configuration?

[image]

They only appear if I search for them.

[image]

---

I added them to a category.

[image]

But it does not appear

[image]

Comment: Did you create a category to put them in?

Comment: @JulienLachal Yeah Julien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go  to command line and fire below commands

```
cd yourMagentoDirectory 

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

after this commands refresh your magento cache.

Comment: I did and nothing changed on the homepage

Comment: @RafaelaCordeiro as marius said you cannot see those product in home page but you can see this products in category

Comment: Yes, I did as he asked. But it does not appear, in the post that I showed shows in the last image

Answer (score 0):

The products are not supposed to appear on the homepage unless you create a block that displays the products and attach that block to the homepage.
I advice you to create a category, assign your 2 products to the category.
Then you should see in the top menu section the link to the category page and clicking it will display your products.

Comment: I added new photos

Comment: @RafaelaCordeiro. rebuild the indexes.